# Firestore query options swift

Tags: swift, filter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem related to query Firestore. Currently, I have Firestore structure as below.

[image]

I want to create a search system where the user has the option either to filter programme, status and category. Below is the source code for the filter:

```
var filterProg = ""
var filterStat = ""
var filterCat = ""

   @IBAction func filterButtonDidTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.agencyList.removeAll()

  db.collection("fund")


 .whereField("programme", isEqualTo: filterProg )


 .whereField("status", isEqualTo: filterStat )


 .whereField("category", isEqualTo: filterCat )

        .getDocuments()
            {
                (querySnapshot, err) in

                if let err = err
                {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
                }
                else
                {
                    //  var agencyNumber = 0
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let agencyy = data["age"] as? String ?? ""
                        let title = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                        let agencyId = document.documentID
                        print(title)
                        print(agencyy)
                        print(agencyId)

                        let newModel = DisplayModel(agency: title, agencyId: agencyId)
                        self.agencyList.append(newModel)
                       // self.originalData.append(title)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
    }

}
```

from the code above variables `filterProg`, `filterStat`, and `filterCat` will change from an empty string `""`, to some string from UIPicker depend on users choice. The problem is, if the user decides to filter for `filterProg` (program) and `filterStat` (status) only, the variable `fileterCat` will remain empty string `""`. This caused data from firestore to display nothing. I have tried something like: check if the variable is an empty string or not as below:

```
let query = db.collection("fund")

if filterProg != "" {
 query.whereField("programme", isEqualTo: filterProg )
}

if filterProg != "" {
 query.whereField("status", isEqualTo: filterStat )
}
 if filterProg != "" {
 query.whereField("category", isEqualTo: filterCat )
}
    .getDocuments() //got error here
        {
            (querySnapshot, err) in
```

I got an error on `.getDocuments()`

> Reference to member 'getDocuments' cannot be resolved without a
>   contextual type

I am stuck with this problem for a week. Actually, is it possible to make filter option on Firestore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible at present, but a workaround may be to create your query depending on the outcome of testing your fields for valid strings.

```
var query: Query!

if /* some condition */ {

    query = db.collection("fund").whereField("programme", isEqualTo: filterProg)

} else if /* condition */ {

    query = db.collection("fund").whereField("status", isEqualTo: filterStat)

} // etc

query.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            //
        }
```

Improvements to firestore queries are on the radar:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/321

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to first construct the base of your query:

```
let query = db.collection("fund")
```

Then add the conditions to your query based on the values the user entered:

```
if filterProg != "" {
 query = query.whereField("programme", isEqualTo: filterProg )
}
if filterProg != "" {
 query = query.whereField("status", isEqualTo: filterStat )
}
if filterProg != "" {
 query = query.whereField("category", isEqualTo: filterCat )
}
```

And then finally get the documents matching the query:

```
query.getDocuments() {
  (querySnapshot, err) in ...
```